# Facility location Optimization packages for R?

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve a optimization problem. How can i find facility location optimization packages in R ? Could anyone can help me about it ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. That question is rather broad and not the kind of question for this forum. The mission of Stackoverflow is to help you with specific programming issues.

Comment: That being said, there are people better informed then me but I do not think there is a package for this particular problem. I do not even think that it would make sense to create one because in the end every problem must be stated mathematically and maths does not care much about the underlying field application (except for those cases which are linked to very specific mathematical challenges which I do not think would be the case here). If you want to take a closer look yourself: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html provides a vast overview over optimisation packages.

Answer (score 2):

Facility location problems are often optimized using mixed integer programming (MIP).

See the optimization packages ROI: http://roi.r-forge.r-project.org/

and ompr: https://dirkschumacher.github.io/ompr/

You can formulate MIP optimization models directly in ROI.  ROI can link to a collection of solvers.  ompr is a model management package for building models.  It then calls ROI functions for solving.  Model construction using ompr is somewhat easier that using ROI only.

Here is an example warehouse location model formulated using ompr and the glpk solver:

https://dirkschumacher.github.io/ompr/articles/problem-warehouse-location.html